# Very small fractions and 'double' type

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm using a formula of 1/x, where x could be very big (bigger than 1000)

When I use 'double' type, I always get zero!

For example:

```
        int numOfDays = 1000;

        double result = 1 / numOfDays;
```

Which type can I use?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) and assigning the result to a double.

Change one of the operands to a `double` or `float`, and you will be OK.

```
int numOfDays = 1000;
double result = 1.0 / numOfDays;
```

Or:

```
int numOfDays = 1000;
double result = 1D / numOfDays;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just started to write the same thing! Stupid mistake :)